# How to use strsplit() to access elements in an R list?

Tags: regex, r, list, strsplit

I have an R list `list1`, whereby one field was made to be two strings concatenated with together.

When we acces the field `field3` for `list1`, it looks like this

```
list1$field2

 [1] "stringA, stringB"    
 [2] "stringA, stringB"      
 [3] "stringA, stringB" 
 [4] "stringA, stringB" 
 [5] "stringA, stringB" 
 [6] "stringA, stringB"             
 ....
```

I would only like to access the entries "stringB", and ignore "stringA".

If I use something like `strsplit()`, I get the following:

```
strsplit(list1$field2, ",")
[[1]]
[1] "stringA"
[2] "stringB"
[[2]]
[1] "stringA"
[2] "stringB"
....
```

This is a list where each member has two elements. How do I only access the second element? Is there a way to make this more syntactically compact?

Comment: `lapply(strsplit(list1$field2, ","), `[`, 2)` will get the second element of each component of the second list you show (i.e. the list returned by `strsplit()`).

Comment: @GavinSimpson - `lapply(strsplit(list1$field2, ","), \`[\`, 2)` I think you mean - have to escape the backticks in comments.

Comment: You can use `"["` with `lapply`. Don't need backticks.

Comment: @thelatemail yes, I forget that I need to escape them here... Thanks! :-)

Comment: @42 Yes, you are right you don't need them, but they are the canonical way to refer to functions that need masking from the parser. That `"..."` works is, IIRC, some extra sugar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "tidyverse" approach similar to suggestion in comments by @GavinSimpson:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

x <- rep("stringA, stringB", 10)

str_split(x, ", ") %>% map_chr(`[`, 2)
#>  [1] "stringB" "stringB" "stringB" "stringB" "stringB" "stringB" "stringB"
#>  [8] "stringB" "stringB" "stringB"
```

- `str_split()` acts like `strsplit()`.
- `map_chr()` acts like `lapply()`, but also converts resulting list to a character vector.

For your problem, substitute `x` for `list1$field2`

Answer (score 2):

```
strsplit(list1$field2, ",")[[1]][[2]]
```

==> will access 2nd element

```
strsplit(list1$field2, ",")[[1]][[5]]
```

==> will access 5th element

Answer (score 1):

Here is function which is fast for converting a 2 element string to a data frame:

```
strToDf<-function (list){
  slist<-strsplit(list, ",")
  x<-sapply(slist, FUN= function(x) {x[1]})
  y<-sapply(slist, FUN= function(x) {x[2]})
  #x<-as.numeric(x)
  #y<-as.numeric(y)
  df<-data.frame(x=x, y=y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  return(df)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will read that vector and parse as a text file, so then you can just take the second "column"

```
 scan(text=list1$field2, what=list("",""))[[2]]
Read 6 records
[1] "stringB" "stringB" "stringB" "stringB" "stringB" "stringB"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strsplit(list1$field2, ",")[[1]][2]
```

will access the second element.